# What is the meanning of "should be happening"?

Tags: modal-verbs, progressive-aspect

An example from TED:

> Those conversations **should be happening** in a good marriage, not after it is broken.

And I have heard it many times so far, but I am not sure what exactly it means. Does it a more polite or uncertain way to say something that will happen?

Comment: *Should* is different from *will*. The sun will come up tomorrow. I don't know if you will see it, but you *should be* facing East to make that happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a different context, the phrase "X should be happening" would indicate an expectation rather than a surety.

Examples:

*The guests should be arriving soon*
This means something like: I have not confirmed the exact location of our guests, but I expect that they will arrive soon.

*When is the water going to start boiling?*
*It should be happening now.*
Again, this would mean: I haven't actually checked the pot, but (since it's been on the stove for a while) I expect that it's boiling.

---

**On the other hand**

*Should* can also indicate an obligation, or a recommendation, so *X should be happening* can also mean *you are obligated to/it's recommended that you do X*.

Examples:

*You should be doing your homework*
This might be what a parent would say to their child when they find the child playing video games before having finished their homework.

*I manage two employees; how do I know if they're happy at work?*
*Conversations with your employees about job satisfaction should be happening regularly.*
Here, the *should* expresses the sense of a recommendation; it's recommended that you regularly talk to your employees about job satisfaction.

---

So how do we know which sense applies in your case, or in any given case?  Context.

Because the speaker says that this "should be happening in a good marriage" and "not after it's broken," it appears that he is making a recommendation.  That is, this is what you *should* do if you want a good marriage.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand from the given point that expression means is supposed to be happening as just the way the thing are happening naturally.